# How to disable pointer-events on all elements of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use Violentmonkey to disable pointer events on `load` for all webpages so that I get to see the page instead of an element that gets inadvertently activated on hover. Such elements sometimes block a large portion of the page, so I have to move my mouse outside that region to be able to see the actual content.

Here is the javascript snippet of code that achieves this goal:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.body.style.pointerEvents = "none";
});

['mousemove', 'scroll', 'keydown', 'click', 'touchstart'].forEach(function(event)  {
  window.addEventListener(event, () => {
    document.body.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  }, { once: true });
});
```

While this code works in most cases, it fails to work in some other. For example, it disables pointer events everywhere in GitHub except for the header menu, which is actually where a lot of hoverable elements reside.

Additionally, if the mouse is not even on one of the header's hoverable elements, I sometimes see them opened on page load, hence the script! See the pointer on "Copilot" in the following screenshot.

How can I modify the code to make it work on all elements?

[image: Exmaple]